# Magento 2 - Hiding prices by customer

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, customer-attribute

I am trying to hide prices when a specific customer attribute is set to "true". 
Because of FP-Caching, this has been very difficult to accomplish.

I can't update the FinalPriceBox directly with plugin, as this data gets cached and switching the value on / off on customer entity doesn't update on frontend with caching enabled. Attempting to disable cache for that block alone actually disables cache for the entire page which is no good.

I have also attempted to create my own component, that can hide or display the block and provide the customer attribute via plugin for Magento\Customer\CustomerData\Customer => Magento_Customer/js/view/customer-data. 
However this gives complications on first page loaded after login (data is not upto-date). Also this saves the field into the cookie storage, which would mean that variable can be controlled on client-side cookie.

Any suggestions of an approach to display the price when the customer attribute is "false" and display a custom block when customer attribute is "true"? Must maintain all cacheable blocks.

Maybe adding new section-data that will load specific to my module?

Comment: Hi, you should use a component to store/read from localstorage when possible and an ajax request when not possible ie after the login. Good luck!

Comment: Do you have a tutorial or example of that?

Comment: I never faced your situation so I don't know or have anything that could explain the approach, but I gave an answer here about the localstorage: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/277785/magento-2-customer-name-not-display-in-programmatically-logged-in-user-account/277793#277793

It's a place to start, you will also need a controller for the ajax request

Answer (score 0):

try to make different customer groups instead giving each customer an attribute. Magento keeps **different caches for different customer groups**. So you can easily hide prices (or whatever) for one group and show to other, making check right in the price block. Please take a look at [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/202642/hide-price-for-guest-users) example.