# Magento 2.3.7 - Customer login not working on category pages due to caching

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, full-page-cache, customer-session, ultimo

On category pages, we have a custom code that the prices are only seen to login customers but the customer session is not working on category pages.
After customer login for some categories pages still in the header not showing customer logged In (signout link not coming), and the prices still not visible.

For some category pages, it is working and the signout option is visible in the header.
Also after logout still on some category pages, the customer is logged in and signout option is visible in the header and prices are visible but the customer is already logout.
When I disabled FPC from the backend it is working fine but disabling FPC make the page loading speed very slow.

Comment: Check out this approach: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/322480/59652 It works for me.

Comment: You can use https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/206197/4564.  but remove object manager . use class from __construtct

Comment: You should use `HTTP_CONTEXT` to check whether customer is logged in or not, as customer session has issues with FPC sometimes.

Comment: Custom code to hide/show price is working fine, the main problem is the customer not showing logged in after login on some page. i.e in the header still sign In option is visible after login. The main problem is FPC , how to solve this issue

Comment: @RanjeetSingh might you are not using the default magento login link and template. It may be shown from custom template. Can you please confirm this.

Comment: @RahulBarot yes ultimo theme is installed

Comment: @RanjeetSingh in that case you need to debug and check code how it is rendering the login link in header.

Comment: @RahulBarot It was working fine with the 2.3.1 version but not working with 2.3.6-p1 and 2.3.7 versions